# CSS width not adding up as expected

Tags: css

I have a page with a row of `100px` and 4 columns of `25px` each. I seem to get at odd behavior. Please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GmU2k/

My question is should all of the columns be on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddel

http://jsfiddle.net/GmU2k/2/

```
.column-3 {
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

You gave the width as 25% and a border of 1px. So `4 divs width = 100% + border width`
Thats why 4 divs are not shown in one line. Because there is not enough space.

Once you decrease the width of inner divs then there will be enough space. Or you can remove the border, so that inner divs will have enough space to be shown in a single line.

**Note: The simple concept is there should be enough space for the divs to be shown in single line. If there is not enough space then they will flow to the next line.**

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmU2k/3/)

Better use `box-sizing: border-box` by adding below `css` on `column-3`: That happens because of your `1px` border.

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
```

Comment: Nice to know abut box-sizing. But will this work in all browsers?

Comment: @Narendra I believe that is still on experimental. See this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I went through w3schools and found that this is supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column-3 width to 24%.

Comment: thats not the point. I could do that but was wondering why that was not working

Comment: 1px border occupies your extra 1% :)